# How to include library in Erlang\OTP

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, erlang, erlang-otp, amqpstorm

I'm new in RabbitMQ, I want to use rabbitmq with ssl (AMQPs). Now the issue is when I read the [Erlang/OTP Requirements for TLS Support](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#erlang-otp-requirements), and checked my erlang setup with command **code:all_loaded().** I got list of modules that are loaded in erlang but not found which are required to use ssl over rabbitmq (public_key, crypto, asn1, and ssl).

Upon checking my C:/program files/ erl-24.2.1/lib, I have the folder for respective library but I'm not sure how can I enable those libraries.

Please help me to enable those libraries in erlang otp.

**Note: I'm using this on windows OS.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself working with Erlang's built-in function documentation  :) ([link](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#ensure_loaded-1))

```
> code:is_loaded(crypto).    
false
> code:ensure_loaded(crypto).
{module,crypto}
> code:is_loaded(crypto).    
{file,"c:/ProgramFiles/erl-24.2/lib/crypto-5.0.5/ebin/crypto.beam"}
```